# Visual Basic 2010 Trying to click submit button with no id and only text on it in web browser

Tags: vb.net

Button I am trying to click in webbrowser

```
<button type="submit" class="c-btn c-btn-primary c-pull-right" tabindex="3">sign in</button>
```

My code :

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user_login").SetAttribute("Value", NsTextBox1.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd_login").SetAttribute("Value", NsTextBox2.Text)
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rem_login").InvokeMember("Click")
        Delay(1)
```

The login button clicker would go after the delay(1) part.

Ive been stuck on this for DAYS, done countless searches and I can not find out how to click this using code.

Comment: Have you tried something like WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("loginform").InvokeMember("submit"); ?

Comment: Yes and I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."